# Absolute position of Flutter widgets

Tags: flutter

I need to code an image viewer for images too large to fit on the screen. I want to adjust the position of the image so that I can control which section of the image is visible. My plan was to set the position with a negative value to move it outside the screen area but I can't seem to get that to work. Negative margins don't cut it either. Any other bright ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`Image`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Image-class.html) class has both an `alignment` and `fit` props for this kind of purpose.

For example you could have

```
new Image.asset("name", 
  fit: BoxFit.cover,
  alignment: new Alignment(-1.0, -1.0),
);
```

which would make the image fill its parent but preserve its ratio. And align the image to the top-left of its container.

You can find these properties on `DecorationImage` too, used by `DecoratedBox` and `Container`.

Comment: That allows me to move around the top left corner as needed. I want to change the size of the image too (zoom) but width and height don't seem to be used if "fit" has been specified - I have used BoxFit.none. Can you suggest how that might be done? Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Wrap the image inside a SizedBox

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you.